# Fatal signal 11 SIGSEGV (RxCachedTreadS) when use RxJava with api, room, retrofit

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, android-room, rx-java2

In my application I use RxJava, Some API, Retrofit and Room.

My application intermittently crashes after start process, somtimes it working 10~15 minute.
But it always force finishing showing this error.

**A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x20 in tid 30800 (RxComputation)**

I can't find which code evoke this error.

**MyActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 
       GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (true) {
                viewModel.gatherChangeAfterLastLogin()
                delay(10000L)
            }
        }
}
```

**viewModel.kt**

```
class viewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    fun gatherChangeAfterLastLogin() {
        var a = Observable.fromIterable(someObject...)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe { }

        var b = Observable.fromIterable(someObject...)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe { }

        var c = Observable.fromIterable(someObject...)
                .flatMap {
                    var one = Observable.fromIterable(someObject...).onErrorReturn{ Collections.emptyList() }
                    var two = Observable.fromIterable(someObject...).onErrorReturn{ Collections.emptyList() }
                    var three = Observable.fromIterable(someObject...).onErrorReturn{ Collections.emptyList() }
                    Observable.mergeDelayError(one, two, three)
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({

                }, {

                }, {

                })
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0' 
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0' 
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-converters:2.4.0' 
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

In my opinion, **var c Observable** is suspicious, so even if I comment out and run it, the result is the same.

And, If i change **Schedulers.io()** to **Schedulers.computation()**,
The error details are as follows

**A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x20 in tid 30800 (RxComputation)**

I don't know where the problem occurred because the error comes out like that

Comment: This is not a RxJava issue, because RxJava runs on the Android-Runtime and this issue is because of some libc issue (SIGSEGV). Most likely it is an issue of the Android-Runtime (Android version) or you have a weird android image on your device. Could you please post the content of the tombstone (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug)?